# Is it possible to drag and drop data (String) from a ListView between other apps like Notepad in UWP C#

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to drag and drop data (String) from a ListView between other apps like Notepad.
I know you can drag and drop files but I want to know if dragging and droping an ListViewItem that Contains the string I want to share between apps, Like for example if I'm sharing a string it would make sense if it is dropped into a app containing a text field or anything that allows such data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to drag-drop data between apps. For this purpose you use [DataPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage). In one app you [set the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage.setdata#Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_DataPackage_SetData_System_String_System_Object_), whereas in the second app, upon drop operation you get the data from [DataPackageView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackageview) with [GetDataAsync method.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackageview.getdataasync#Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_DataPackageView_GetDataAsync_System_String_)

So everything depends what data is accepted by the drop target app and how it's being handled there.

Once I've written [small drag-drop sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48176944/2681948) - maybe you will find something usefull there.